# What is the purpose of 'comment' keyword in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, comments

I have found there is the 'comment' keyword in MySQL.(not comment syntax like /* */, #)

But I do not know the reason why there is the 'comment' keyword.

If there is the following table, how could I use the 'comment'?

```
create table Employee(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    create_dt date comment 'the date when employee was hired'
    salary int comment 'salary in EUR',
    primary key (id)
) comment 'The employee table of company AA';
```

Comment: Write comment to explain what the table is used for?!

Comment: I didn't even know `comment` was a keyword in MySQL.  It looks like it's just another way to leave a comment in your SQL code.  I think I would prefer `--` because this is ANSI standard, and IMO easier to spot as being a comment rather than a keyword.

Comment: Comments are more useful when you writing a stored procedures or functions in database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments are a way to store relevant information in the database itself. For example, putting a comment on a column will cause it to be displayed by the `show create table` and `show full columns` commands.

Note that this is *different* to what most people think of as comments in SQL - those are simply statements in scripts that are ignored after being parsed. They do not make their way into any metadata for later retrieval.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the 'comment' keyword is for saving additional information of the column even after executing sql script.
Then, is there a way to get 'column comment' instead of 'column name' when we find some rows?(I am curious about the way like "select salary.comment(??) from Employee where salary > 3000")

Comment: @dolgom, the metadata is held in `information_schema.columns` and you can get at it with something like `select table_schema, table_name, column_name, column_comment from information_schema.columns where table_schema='schema_name' and table_name = 'table_name'`. Combining that with *data* from the table itself would need a cross-join.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @paxdiablo

Comment: If you forget the table or columns with metadata you can also do `show full columns from schema_name.table_name;` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html